# How to set dynamic observedAttributes

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

My goal is to set `observedAttributes` dynamically, so my web component will watch only attributes following a pattern, like a colon (:attr) `<my-element static="value1" :dynamic=${dynamic}/>`
In this case, `<my-element>` should set `observedAttributes` only for the attribute `:dynamic`

The problem is that `static get observedAttributes()` runs before there's even a `this`, explained in https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

So this won't work

```js
static get observedAttributes() {
   return this.getAttributeNames().filter((item) => item.startsWith(':'));
}
```

and of course neither does

```js
constructor() {
        super();
        this._observedAttributes = this.getAttributeNames().filter((item) => item.startsWith(':'));
    }
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return this._observedAttributes;
    }
```

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <my-element static="value1" :dynamic="value2" ></my-element>
    <script>
        class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this._observedAttributes= this.getAttributeNames().filter((item) => item.startsWith(':'));
                console.log('observedAttributes',this._observedAttributes);
            }
            static get observedAttributes() {
                return this._observedAttributes;
            }
            attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
                console.log(name, oldValue, newValue); //doesn't log anything
            }
        }
        customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('setting dynamic attribute. This should trigger attributeChangedCallback. But no.');
            document.querySelector('my-element').setAttribute(':dynamic', 'value3');
        }, 2000);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You then need a Web Component that creates another Web Component (with dynamic observedAttributes)

Comment: or use the MutationObserver API

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Ugh. I don't *want* the overhead of a mutation observer for every single component, some of which *already* have a mutation observer for manual slot assignment.  My list of attributes is fixed, but it's defined in terms of keyed functions in the constructor, so having to define it a second time in a static is redundant and thus error prone.

Comment: Hi Michael, post you (minimal) code in a question. having to define your attributes _twice_ shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [@Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman)'s suggestion, I looked at the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and came up with a simple solution that I think offers more than `observedAttributes`

```html
<my-element static="value1" :dynamic="value2"></my-element>
<script>
  class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
    mutationObserverCallback(mutationList, observer) {
      for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes' &&
          mutation.attributeName.startsWith(':') &&
          mutation.oldValue !== mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)) {
          console.log(`The dynamic ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
        }
      }
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(this.mutationObserverCallback);
      this.mutationObserver.observe(this, {
        attributes: true,
        attributeOldValue: true
      });
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
      this.mutationObserver.disconnect();
    }
  }
  customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('setting dynamic attribute for :dynamic and static attributes. This should trigger mutationObserverCallback for :dynamic only.');
    // ▼ will trigger mutationObserverCallback
    document.querySelector('my-element').setAttribute(':dynamic', 'value3');
    // ▼ will not trigger mutationObserverCallback
    document.querySelector('my-element').setAttribute('static', 'value4');
  }, 200);
</script>
```

Comment: please keep in mind that the MutationObserver does not _immediately_ report any changes but only as part of a future "microtask". This is in contrast to the `attributeChangedCallback` which is invoked immediately after an attribute was changed. As a consequence, this code should perhaps **NOT** be marked as the correct answer...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following shim that will add the functionality of observing change of attributes dynamically on every instance of the element. You can define attributes that will be observed on all instances by default and you can add at the runtime attributes that will be observed only at a particular instance.

```js
class BaseClass extends HTMLElement {
  constructor({stat = BaseClass} = {}) {
    super()
        // console.log('constructor')
        this.#stat = stat
        this.#setAttribute = this.setAttribute
        this.setAttribute = function(name, value){
            // console.log('attribute', name, this.observedAttributes, (this.observedAttributes.includes(name)))
            if (this.observedAttributes.includes(name)){
                // do your stuff
                // console.log('attribute includes')
                this.attributeChangedCallback(name, this.getAttribute(name), value)
            }
            else {
            // do what you want
            }
            this.#setAttribute(name, value)
        }
  }
    #observedAttributes = []
    get observedAttributes(){
        return [...this.#stat.observedAttributes, ...this.#observedAttributes]
    }
    #setAttribute = null
    #stat = null
    addObservedProp(name){
        this.#observedAttributes.push(name)
    }
  connectedCallback() {}
  disconnectedCallback() {}
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log('change', name, oldValue, newValue)
    }
  adoptedCallback() {}
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }
}

window.customElements.define('base-com', BaseClass)

const test = document.getElementById('test')
test.setAttribute('d', 'status 1')
test.addObservedProp('d')
test.setAttribute('d', 'status 2')
console.log(test)
```

```html
<base-com id="test">Base com</base-com>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).